# Fourier transform plot

Tags: signal-processing, sampling, fourier

> A continuous-time signal x with bandwidth \$\frac{20π}{3}\$ rad/sec is
> sampled with sampling period \$T_s = 0.1\$ seconds to obtain a
> discrete-time signal \$x_s[n] = x(nT_s)\$ for all n. The discrete-time
> Fourier transform \$X_s\$ of the sampled signal is shown below:
> [image]
>
> Let \$X\$ be the continuous-time Fourier transform of the input signal
> \$x\$. Sketch \$X(ω)\$ vs \$ω\$ for \$−10π ≤ ω ≤ 10π\$. Label all
> features of your plot.

Apparently, we can deduce using the equation \$X_s(\omega)=\frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X\left(\frac{\omega-2\pi k}{T_s}\right)\$ that the plot should look something like this:

[image]

Could someone please clarify how you would do this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a homework, so I'll only say that sampling causes [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Folding) (or frequency folding). If the original signal was properly band limited (is it the case here?), will it have aliasing if the sampling is removed?

Answer (score 0):

For understanding aliasing, just simulate this circuit.
A complex signal is "difficult", shown here as the sum of 3 sinusoidal signals.
Hope this can help.

[image]